# Htaccess : multiple parameters and nested parentheses

Tags: arrays, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got some project where I redirect every request on `index.php`, with various `GET` parameters.

Currently, I'm using this kind of htaccess (this is only an extract, and I changed parameters name to `a, b, c...`, in order to simplify the problem) :

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$                   index.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$          index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]
(...)
```

It works (well), but I was thinking about a way to minify those lines into a single one.
**The idea is to have some nested parentheses to 'generate' all `GET` parameters**, but it seems it won't work as easily as I thought.

Here is what I've made so far :

```
RewriteRule 
    ^(?:([\w-]+)\/)*([\w-]+)\.html$ 
    index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7&h=$8&i=$9 [L]
```

`GET` result for the url `http://website.com/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9.html` :

```
array(9) { 
   ["a"]=> string(1) "8" 
   ["b"]=> string(1) "9" 
   ["c"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["d"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["e"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["f"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["g"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["h"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["i"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

Instead of get `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=3`... I only receive the two last parameters. Notice that the `RewriteRule` is executed, then I know my regex match.

Any idea ?

Comment: What's the real problem you are trying to solve? Using regexes is not always the best solution.

Comment: I put it in bold : use a single RewriteRule instead of 9 to do the same job. I don't really care of performances in this case, it's more a curiosity question.

Comment: So basically you want to know if it is possible to write a regex to convert a url into a something that has a lot of GET parameters. That should be possible, but it also means that you are removing any GET parameters that are specified on the original url. That means it's not really suitable for any project.

Comment: It already remove any `GET` parameters, but I exclusively use rewritten urls, so I'm sure to never have any problem with this. I'm just searching for a shorter way to write my rules, no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule 
    ^([\w-]+)(?:\/([\w-]+)(?:\/([\w-]+)(?:\/([\w-]+)(?:\/([\w-]+)(?:\/([\w-]+)(?:\/([\w-]+)(?:\/([\w-]+)(?:\/([\w-]+))?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?\.html$ 
    index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7&h=$8&i=$9 [L]
```

Untested, but I think this does what you want. Note that it works for 1 to 9 parameters, it requires at least one.
Also note that any GET parameter that was present in the original url could be removed this way.

Comment: As said by @Sat, this solution is ugly :) Anyway, that's a working single line solution, so you got my vote. Thanks you both for explanation.

Comment: Thanks. The solution is ugly, which is why I first wanted to know that it really is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For the record: do consider using a PHP-based approach: pass the entire requested URI to PHP, and then you could handle the whole thing in PHP, which is a whole lot easier, very likely safer, and maybe even faster, than doing the magic with mod_rewrite.

I mean something like this:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ switchboard.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

then in switchboard.php:

```
list($_GET['a'], $_GET['b'], $_GET['c']) = explode( '/', $_GET['uri']);
require 'index.php';
```

(if the super-long list() looks cumbersome, you may use some clever one-liner mapping technique)

Anyhow, the regex question is certainly interesting, but it's a generic PCRE thing. The phenomenon is called "repeated capture group": whenever you repeat a capture group with the Kleene star like you do, only the very last iteration will actually be captured (in our case, the matches 1,2..7 were discarded, and only the 8 was kept) - imagine it as a buffer you keep overwriting with newer and newer matches. It makes a lot of sense, if you think about it.

A solution is to use as many groups as you actually want to capture, by making the earlier groups optional - it's incredibly awkward to write and read (indeed, Arjan just posted it, and it's a headache just to look at it), and also very inefficient in this case. A much simpler solution is to just capture the whole thing and split it.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for putting a name on my problem, I found an article which detail it : http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html And ya, without the possibility to capture each group, write a single line rule became awkward !